# How to show that the cardinality of the following set is $2^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Here $n>2$.

Suppose that we can write $$\mathbb{F}_2^n=A_1\cup A_2,\ A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset,$$
where it is known that $$0\in A_1,$$
and there exists a unique $b\in A_2$ such that $$b\neq x+y$$ for any $x, y\in A_1.$
I need to show that $$|A_1|=2^{n-1}.$$
My effort: I have checked several examples by taking $n=3, 4$ but in all those examples, the above mentioned result is true.

Then I tried to write each element of $A_2$ as sum of an element of $A_1$ and $b$ but unable to reach at the final result. Please help.

Comment: You asked this question already; this is exactly the same as [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4449517/742), but with the complement of $A_1$ named here. Please do not repost the same question.

Comment: No. You can recheck that both the questions are different and carry different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a basis of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ given by $\{v, ..., v_{n-1}, b\}$. For any $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n, x = c_1v_1 + ... +c_{n-1}v_{n-1} + c_n b$ with each $c_i = 0, 1$. Let $x \in A_1$ have the $b$ coefficient on in its above basis representation, i.e.,  have $c_n = 1$. As $x \ne b$ then at least one other $c_i =1$. Then the vector $x'$ with the same coefficients in the basis as $x$ *except* at $c_n$ (i.e., with $c_n=0$) cannot be in $A_1$ (as $x+x' = b$). Moreover, as $b$ is the only vector in $A_2$ that cannot be written as a sum of two vectors in $A_1$ there must be $y_1, y_2 \in A_1$ such that $y_1 + y_2 = x'$. But then there is $y_1' \in A_2$ such that $y_1' + y_1 = b$ (differs from $y_2$ only at the $c_n$-th coefficient in the basis representation); likewise for $y_2'$. In this way, we establish a bijection between $A_1$ and $A_2$. Therefore $|A_1| = 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: It is clear from the proof that $|A_1|\leq |A_2|$ but it is not clear how $|A_2|\leq |A_1|$? Please elaborate it more.

Comment: You might be right (I'm tired)-can you say how you think the proof still makes this possible?

Comment: A rough answer: if $|A_2| > |A_1|$ there would be another element in $A_2$ that was not equal to the sum $x + y $ for all $x, y \in A_1$.

Comment: Can you please provide proof of the same? That is there will be another element that can not be written as sum of two elements.